# Properties of the convolution function

Tags: real-analysis

Exercise from my TA

Let $f,g,h:\Bbb R \to \Bbb C$ be 1-periodic continuous functions. The periodic convolution $f \ast g$ is defined by$f\ast g = \int_0^1f(x-y)g(y)dy$

(1) Prove that $f\ast g $ is continuous

(2) Prove that $f\ast g = g \ast f$

(3) Prove that $f\ast (g \ast h) = (f\ast g) \ast h$

(4) Prove that $\widehat {f\ast g} (n) = \widehat f(n)\widehat g(n)$

Hint: to prove that f ∗ g is continuous,
you will have to do something like use the fact that f is bounded, and g is
uniformly continuous, or vice versa. To prove that f ∗ g = g ∗ f, you will need
to use the periodicity to “cut and paste” the interval [0, 1]

My work: (1) following the hint, I am having problem with showing that g is uniformly continuous. I was going to use the theorem the fact that "If $\Bbb R$ is compact, then f is continuous iff f is uniformly continuous." But then I noticed that "$\Bbb R$" is not compact. For the boundedness of $g$, suppose $g$ is not bounded, then g can not form a 1-periodic continuous function, therefore a contradiction. (I am not quite sure if my reasoning is correct). I am also not sure where these information will lead me though.

(2) I have no idea

(3) I feel I need to use the result from (2) and show

$\int_0^1f(x_0-y)(\int_0^1g(x_1-y)h(y)dy)dy = \int_0^1(\int_0^1f(x-y)g(y)dy) h(y)dy$ (I am a bit lost myself)

(4) definition: for any function $ f\in C(\frac{\Bbb R}{\Bbb Z}, \Bbb R)$ and any integer $n\in \Bbb Z$ we define the nth Fourier coefficient of f, denoted $\widehat f(n):= <f,e_n>=\int_0^1 f(x)e^{-2\pi inx}dx$

Thank you all for the help

Textbook: Analysis II by Tao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $$h(x)=(f\ast g )(x)= \int_0^1f(x-y)g(y)dy$$
(1) We need to show that $$x_n\to x\Longrightarrow h(x_n)\to h(x)$$but this is straight-forward. As $f(x-y)$ is continuous in $x$ for any $y\in \Bbb R$, we obtain$$|x_n-x|<\delta\Longrightarrow -\epsilon<f(x_n-y)-f(x-y)<\epsilon\\\Longrightarrow\\-\epsilon|g(y)|<f(x_n-y)g(y)-f(x-y)g(y)<\epsilon|g(y)|\\\Longrightarrow\\-\epsilon\int _0^1|g(y)|dy<\int _0^1f(x_n-y)g(y)dy-\int _0^1f(x-y)g(y)dy<\epsilon\int _0^1|g(y)|dy\\\Longrightarrow\\$$since $g(x)$ is continuous on the compact set $[0,1]$, then is bounded and therefore by defining  $$M\triangleq \int _0^1|g(y)|dy$$we obtain$$-M\epsilon<h(x_n)-h(x)<M\epsilon$$which completes the proof on continuity of $h(x)$.

(2) A simple substitution of $y\to x-y$

(3) Just a simple multiplication of three integrals and rearrange them (using (2) doesn't help out)

> **Edit**
>
> (4) Following the definition of *Fourier series*, we can
>   write$$\widehat{h}[n]{=\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x-y)g(y)e^{-2\pi
> > inx}dydx\\=\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x-y)g(y)e^{-2\pi
> > inx}dxdy\\=\int_0^1g(y)\int_0^1 f(x-y)e^{-2\pi
> > inx}dxdy\\=\int_0^1g(y)\int_{y}^{y+1} f(u)e^{-2\pi
> > in(u+y)}dudy\\=\int_0^1g(y)e^{-2\pi iny}\int_{y}^{y+1} f(u)e^{-2\pi
> > inu}dudy\\\overset{a}{=}\int_0^1g(y)e^{-2\pi iny}\int_{0}^{1}
> > f(u)e^{-2\pi inu}dudy\\=\int_0^1g(y)e^{-2\pi
> > iny}\underbrace{\left[\int_{0}^{1} f(u)e^{-2\pi
> > inu}du\right]}_{\widehat{f}[n]}dy\\=\int_0^1g(y)e^{-2\pi
> > iny}\widehat{f}[n]dy\\=\widehat{f}[n]\cdot\int_0^1g(y)e^{-2\pi
> > iny}dy\\={\widehat{f}[n]}{\widehat{g}[n]}}$$
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> a) follows from the fact that the integrand is a periodic function
>   with a period of $1$ and therefore integrating it over *any* interval
>   with length $1$, yields to the same result.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, the answers for the first and second question are a delight to me. I have found the definition for the $\widehat f$ in the book and updated it in the question, do you think you help me with it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure! First, glad I could help you with this problem. Second, I will add & edit my answer to cover the part d). Still trying to prove :)

Comment: I appreciate any question if you had....

Answer (score 1):

Answer for 4): $ \widehat {f*g} (n)=\int_0^{1} (f*g)(x)e^{-2\pi i nx} dx =\int_0^{1}\int_0^{1} f(x-y)g(y)e^{-2\pi i nx} dydx $. Interchanging the integrals we get $ \widehat {f*g} (n)=\int_0^{1} [\int_0^{1} f(x-y)e^{-2\pi i nx} dx] g(y)dy $. In the inside integral make the substitution $z=x-y$. Using periodicity the inside integral becomes $\hat f (n) e^{-2\pi i ny}$. Hence $ \widehat {f*g} (n)=\hat f (n)\hat g (n)$